# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectBox is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

I'm using the code below to select options from drop down, but I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectBox is not a function.
```

in console. I'm going to use [jquery-selectBox](https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox).

My code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("SELECT").selectBox();
        $("SELECT").selectBox('settings', {
            'menuTransition': 'fade',
            'menuSpeed': 'fast'
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in the body tag I get a select field:

```
<select class="selectBox">
    <option value="0">Login Type</option>
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Customer</option>
</select>
```

I included all JavaScript sources in my code, but still it's giving me the error. Any solution?

Comment: Did you include this in your page `<script src="jquery.selectbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: yes I am added it

Comment: Well, it works for me when the selectbox.js is properly linked, with a correct path

Comment: I voted to close this as _"a simple typographical error"_ where the linked library's path were incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use [**jQuery selectBox**](https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox), just load it properly on your page (e.g. [**via CDN**](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.selectbox)).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").selectBox();
  $("select").selectBox('settings', {
    'menuTransition': 'fade',
    'menuSpeed': 'fast'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectbox/1.2.0/jquery.selectBox.js"></script>

<select class="selectBox">
  <option value="0">Login Type</option>
  <option value="1">Admin</option>
  <option value="2">Customer</option>
</select>
```

### Note

To use your markup more efficiently, in this case, use your element's `class` attribute and its value `selectBox` to select it using jQuery, e.g.:

Your markup:

```
<select class="selectBox">
```

Select it via:

```
$(".selectBox").selectBox();
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working. What was the issue in my code?

Comment: The only issue is the linked library, and no "need" to use the elements class, it work as is in OP original code, using the element type

Comment: As there is no real "code issue" here and the question/its answer has no value for future users, it should be closed as _"a simple typographical error"_ where the linked library's path were incorrect.

Comment: @LGSon, the choice is on you, I don't have neither the reputation nor the ability to do otherwise. If you think, that **somebody** in the future won't find this question and the answer useful, then do it, close it.

Comment: No, it is not me, it is **all users** here that should take responsibility and keep SO a good place for coders, with high quality answers, you included, so think about that next time, before posting an answer. Or you really believe a file path typo is of value?

Comment: Also, since you state _"since your select element has a `selectBox` class, access it via `$(".selectBox")`"_, users might get the impression that is needed, so delete that, or I will have to downvote as it is not true.

Comment: @LGSon, okay, but can I include that point, at least in the bottom of the answer to encourage users to use their markup more efficiently?